# Resultado com ponto flutuante para variável decimal

Tags: c#

Tenho a seguinte variável:

```
decimal resultado = 0.0m;
```

Preciso atribuir o resultado de uma divisão a essa variável:

```
resultado = (1 / 2) * (-1);
```

O resultado tem sido `0`, mas deveria ser `-0.5`. Acredito que preciso fazer algum tipo de conversão. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só colocar o m para representar o decimal, deste modo sem o m, é um inteiro, desconsiderando as casas decimais.

resultado = (1m / 2m) * (-1m);